# how do i Run Python script while user login

Tags: python

I have a menu.py script that I want to run every time a user makes a login to the machine.
in menu.py user need to chose what to do via numbers.
for example

1. traceroute
2. sh ip route
   script (menu.py) is working locally without any problem

i want when user NOC ssh to this machine (centos 7) he'll get straight the menu with the numbers to chose.

Would appreciate help
Thanks Rafi

Answer (score 0):

In linux server file exist that run your script or command when you login to specific user or all user one of this file is /etc/bashrc that this file exist for all user in home directory but name ~/.bash_bashrc or ~/.bashrc
Enough you google about it. Be success.